# Android image slideshow maker with animation, affacet

Tags: android, image, video, slideshow

I am going to create an application as a picture slideshow maker. But I dont know which library will help me to create the video from a list of image.

I found out some suggestion about FFMEGP for android. I tried it out, but it's not smooth, no animation, no affect. I am not sure if I can customize it.

for ex: I want to create an application like this one : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.scoompa.slideshow

this app is awesome, a lot of image transitions, affect style, adding text, icon.

would someone please help me to understand which library or solution they re using !

I am very appreciated! thanks all in advance.

Comment: have you found anything useful?

Comment: Do you have any solution, the same i have found it, so.